# Having issues resizing an image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to resize an image to a specific size, it gets resized but cropped as well. What am I doing wrong?

my code:

```
cv::Mat Processor::process_image(cv::Mat& message)
{
    float scale_down = 0.5;
    cv::Mat resized_message;
    cv::resize(message, resized_message, cv::Size(), scale_down, scale_down);
    return resized_message;
}

int main()
{
    cv::namedWindow("view", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    ...
    resized_image = process_image(image);
    cv::imshow("view", resized_image);
    cv::waitKey(30); 
}
```

This one is my source image:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I tried the exact code you shared and the results are fine. Are you missing a point in the other part of the code you didn't share with us ? Because also the method u are using seems fine

Comment: Its a ROS application where one node reads the image and sends it over to the processor node.

Comment: I think the error is not in the resize function but somewhere else

Comment: Your error is definitely somewhere else, I just tested your resize method and it produces the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `mono8` in my publish function produces the error.

```cpp
img_publisher.publish(cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "mono8", message_to_publish.get_image()).toImageMsg());
```

because if I publish the image as `bgr8` it works fine.

```
img_publisher.publish(cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", message_to_publish.get_image()).toImageMsg());
```

So I need to convert the image to grayscale after resizing.